# Деталь ручки от ящичка

Tags: названия

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как называется деталь ручки, насаженная на скобу (вращающийся цилиндр)?

Comment: Хватовая часть ручки.

Answer (score 1):

Это рукоять. Она не насажена (это невозможно), а посажена, хотя, как вариант, возможна состыковка скобы внутри рукояти в процессе монтажа ручки на фасаде двери.